# Block access to history for anonymous users on Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I don't want unregistered (un-signed-in) users to be able to access revision history on my Mediawiki install. I have found some past SE questions regarding hiding the tab via CSS, but I wish to actually block access to the entire "history" page, even via direct URL access.

There are many powerful plugins for restricting user access in various complex ways available, but I was hoping there is a simple "off-switch" somewhere for this functionality before I start setting up large-scale extensions.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Other_restrictions suggests that there is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to add this lines of code to bottom of your LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgHooks['MediaWikiPerformAction'][] = function( $output, $article, $title, $user, $request, $wiki ) {
  if( ( !$user || $user->isAnon() ) && ( $request->getVal('action') == 'history' ) ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Please note that this solution require PHP 5.5 + and mediawiki 1.25+

Comment: This snippet is very useful to me, can you advise me how to do it not on anonymous users, but on a specific group ?

Comment: Sure, just replace part `( !$user || $user->isAnon() )` by `( $user && in_array('my_custom_group', $user->getGroups() ) )` , where `my_custom_group` is your target group

Comment: It works as a charm, but I want to add that you have to create a true custom group: it doesn't work with built-in groups like "bureaucrat" or "user".

Comment: You can try to replace `$user->getGroups()` with `$user->getEffectiveGroups()` , this one should track all automatic groups including `*` (anonymous) and `user`

Comment: Thanks ! It works very nice. I changed a bit the code you gave me, since I wanted "bureaucrat" group to access history, but not "user" group.

    function BlockHistoryUsers( $output, $article, $title, $user, $request, $wiki ) {
  if( ( $user && in_array('bureaucrat', $user->getEffectiveGroups() ) ) && ( $request->getVal('action') == 'history' ) ) {
    return true;
  } elseif( ( $user && in_array('user', $user->getEffectiveGroups() ) ) && ( $request->getVal('action') == 'history' ) ) {
 return false;  
  }
    return true;
}

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to add the code on the latest 1.32 build and it threw a server error 500. It would appear that they have depracated wgHooks alltogether. I was able to accomplish the same thing by using the Lockdown extension, see here:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown

I've used this option in the LocalSettings.php

```
$wgActionLockdown['history'] = [ 'user' ];
```